# dell g3 fingerprint ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, dell, fingerprint-reader

Fingerprint reader is not detected on brand new dell g3, it comes with ubuntu 16.04 pre-installed.

here is the output of lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a368 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a369 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a335 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30d (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0113 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

here is the output of lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 27c6:5301  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:568a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 24ae:1100  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Update :** 
This is the the name of the fingerprint sensor device : Goodix GF3208

No support from Dell for this device yet
https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/No-driver-for-fingerprint-scanner-Goodix-GF3208-on-Linux/m-p/6242579

And it is not supported by fprint
https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html

Comment: Why not ask Dell support if it is preinstalled?

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried their chat support but not helpful , and they don't post ubuntu drivers on their site like windows

Comment: Hello @AdhamSaad check my answer it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

After searching on Google I found this solution and this worked for me check the original post [here](https://gist.github.com/ozturkoktay/d4b345503e3a1a8a8f969b1381b9a3e4)

```
sudo sh -c 'cat > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-dell.list << EOF
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-dell public
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-oem public
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-somerville public
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ focal-somerville-melisa public
EOF'
```

**Note :** you have to put this whole command one time with that's why whole command is in `''`

and than put these commands one by one

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F9FDA6BED73CDC22
sudo apt update -qq

sudo apt install oem-somerville-melisa-meta libfprint-2-tod1-goodix oem-somerville-meta tlp-config -y

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:boltgolt/howdy -y
sudo apt update -qq
sudo apt install howdy -y
```

Comment: Unfortunately, repositories mentioned above don't contain drivers for `27c6:5301`, which is the sensor in question.